# What to do before you change your Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id

I have an apple ID in A country, and now I get a apple ID in B country. I am about to switch to the second apple ID. Switching ID may potentially cause problems, like data loss, information loss and etc.

I have noticed that the manual written by Apple discussed: [What to do **after** you change your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5796).

I am asking: Apple ID: What to do **BEFORE** you change your Apple ID, in order to protect the data, and transfer safely and seamlessly.

Comment: Protect what data? What are you worried about losing exactly?

Comment: Like contacts, photos.